# Displaying and Ordering based off the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

At the moment, I have my data broken down into month intervals. This is how I want it to be displayed, but I'm trying to only display `ordered_by` for those that have 300 or more total in the `LoadCount` for the entire table. So basically, I want to throw out any of the `ordered_by` that dont have at least 300

```
SELECT YEAR(stop.actual_arrival) AS Year, MONTH(stop.actual_arrival) AS Month, COUNT(stop.id) AS DeliveryCount, orders.ordered_by, COUNT(DISTINCT orders.id) 
              AS LoadCount
FROM     stop INNER JOIN
                  (SELECT company_id, order_id, tractor_id
                   FROM      billing_history
                   GROUP BY order_id, tractor_id, company_id) AS derivedtbl_1 ON stop.company_id = derivedtbl_1.company_id AND stop.order_id = derivedtbl_1.order_id INNER JOIN
              tractor ON derivedtbl_1.company_id = tractor.company_id AND derivedtbl_1.tractor_id = tractor.id INNER JOIN
              orders ON derivedtbl_1.company_id = orders.company_id AND derivedtbl_1.order_id = orders.id
WHERE  (orders.order_type_id IN ('12', '13')) AND (stop.stop_type = 'SO') AND (stop.actual_arrival >= DATEADD(month, - 18, GETDATE())) AND (orders.customer_id = 945000) AND 
              (orders.ordered_by IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY YEAR(stop.actual_arrival), MONTH(stop.actual_arrival), orders.ordered_by
ORDER BY Year, Month, orders.ordered_by
```

I keep going back and forth over whether I need a derived table or what... any help would be really appreciated. Thanks guys.

I'm trying to throw out any of the `ordered_by` that don't add up to 300 in total. If they add up to 300 across the entire board, I want them to be displayed, even if they're at 5 for that line.

Comment: Just don't display the ordering fields in your application layer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could make use of the CASE statement inside your select clause to show NULL or orders.ordered_by depending on the value of LoadCount. Here's a page with some examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking to do is throw out any results that don't have `ordered_by` less than 300, you can use a `HAVING` clause with the `GROUP BY`

```
<snip...>
GROUP BY YEAR(stop.actual_arrival), MONTH(stop.actual_arrival), orders.ordered_by
HAVING orders.ordered_by >= 300
ORDER BY Year, Month, orders.ordered_by
```

Comment: I'm trying to throw out any of the `ordered_by` that don't add up to 300 in total. If they add up to 300 across the entire board, I want them to be displayed, even if they're at 5 for that line.

Comment: @JimmyLive In that case, try `HAVING SUM(orders.ordered_by) >= 300`